# How do i Display new HTML page in Navigation tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a web page where there is a navigation bar containing three tabs. Each navigation tab contains a web page. I can't seem to display the website when the user clicks the tab. Can someone help me display the various web pages when a user clicks the different tab buttons? Note i am using bootstrap.

```
    <html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">


    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/shop-item.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('#home').load('home.html');
    $('#data').load('data/data.html');
    $('#sauce').load('sauce/sauces.html');
 </script>


</head>

<body>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home"> Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#data"> Data </a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sauce"> Sauce </a></li>
</ul>




<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
   <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">

            <div id= "mapContainer" class="col-md-12">
                <div id="map-canvas"></div>
            </div>
            <div id = "panelContainer" class="col-md-3 hidden">
             <div  id="right-panel"></div>
           </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated code as per your requirement.

```js
//onloading 

$("#myTab a").each(function () {
            var target = $(this).attr("href");
            $(target).load($(this).attr("data-page"))
        });

//This is for tab click to load page
/*
$("#myTab a").click(function () {
            debugger
            var target = $(this).attr("href");
            alert($(this).attr("data-page"))
            $(target).load($(this).attr("data-page"))

        });
        */
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs" id="myTab">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" data-page="home.html"> Home</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#data" data-page="data.html"> Data </a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sauce" data-page="sauce/sauces.html"> Sauce </a></li>
    </ul>




    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active"></div>
        <div id="data" class="tab-pane fade in"></div>
        <div id="sauce" class="tab-pane fade in"></div>
    </div>
```